# JFrame not opening

Tags: java, swing, variables, jframe

I am supposed to call the Frame constructor in Driver and the JFrame is supposed to open. However, I am getting an error saying the local variable of game, my Frame object, is not used. Does anyone know why this is occurring? Also I am getting an error saying that I need to serialize my Frame class. What is that?

This is my driver class:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player create[] = new Player[2];
        create[0] = new Player();
        create[1] = new Enemy();

        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
            create[x].CharacterCreate();
            //System.out.println(create[x].Print());
        }
        Frame game = new Frame();

}

}
```

This is my Frame class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Frame extends JFrame
{

    public Frame ()
    {
        super();
        //Create Grid Layout
        setSize(300, 200); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);   //makes window visible

        //Creates Grid Layout
        GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(2,3);
        setLayout(gl);
        setTitle("HW11");
        //Creates panel
        JPanel j = new JPanel();
        add (j);

        //Creates Labels
        playerLabel = new JLabel("Player Stats");
        add (playerLabel);
        JLabel space1 = new JLabel(" ");
        add (space1);
        enemeyLabel = new JLabel("EnemyStats");
        add(enemeyLabel);
        JLabel space2 = new JLabel(" ");
        add (space2);


        //Create attack button
        JButton attackButton = new JButton("Attack"); 
        EndingListener updateStats = new EndingListener( );   
        attackButton.addActionListener(updateStats);
        add(attackButton);   //adds button to window

    }

    class EndingListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            update.Attack(update);
            playerLabel.setText(update.Print());
            enemeyLabel.setText(update.Print());
          //  if (Player.gethealth() == 0)
                //System.exit(0);  //terminates the program
          // if (Enemy.gethealth()==0)
            //  System.exit(0);  //terminates the program
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate the help :).

Comment: Don't put "SOLVED" in the title, just accept the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry about the messages you are seeing. These aren't errors that make your program crash, they are simply warnings that the Eclipse handle uses to alert the user of unused variables. You can ignore these for your case. The serial number warning is in the same boat. As for the JFrame, try putting in `setVisible(true)` after every other command in the constructor to make sure all elements of the JFrame that you are adding are visible. Also, in your main method, try creating the frame before the players.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting an error saying the local variable of game, my Frame
>   object, is not used.
>
> Also I am getting an error saying that I need to serialize my Frame
>   class.

This are not errors but [warnings](https://eclipse.org/tm/development/compiler_warnings.php), just ignore them.

It is not mandatory to use the `frame`, because you just use it for display.

Adding the SerialID is also not mandatory if you're not planning on saving your object somewhere.

I'd also suggest you write `setVisible(true)` at the end of your constructor after having added all the components.